# Foursquare API - priceTier missing in Venue details

Tags: foursquare

Smth happened with /venues response in API. priceTier disappeared from attributes->groups unexpectedly :(( Will it be fixed in near future?

Also, where can I get venue tier now?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's back now. Are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: @octopi Yeap. Issue is still here. I see only few priceTier fields in /venuehistory for my user. But a week before I've posted my question there was only few venues WITHOUT this field. You can check venues below. All they had a priceTier field: 4b8e8bd6f964a520f62733e3, 4bc48b902a89ef3b9d68f688, 4bcb120268f976b0e44e6083, 4bcf8461b221c9b6f136d2d0, 4be54f332468c928f3dcff42, 4bf79e114a67c928fcf423cf, 4c0a83766071a5939ca7df32